# What kind of bike do I have

Tags: identify-this-bike

I just bought this Peugeot and having a hard time finding out what year and model it is. Can you please assist and help me. I think the third pic is the serial number: Y71241711.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://www.bikeboompeugeot.com/Serial%20Numbers%20and%20Dates/Serial%20Numbers%20and%20Dates.htm

Comment: Googling around seems to show that a PE10DW is an Aubisque, but I can't locate that model in any of the late 80s Peugeot catalogs on Bike Boom.

Comment: @AndrewHenle  https://www.bikeboompeugeot.com/Brochures%20France/Peugeot%201987%20France%20Brochure/Peugeot_1987_French_Brochure_SaintBernard_Aubisque_BikeBoomPeugeot.JPG

Comment: Great resource. Thanks.  The bike in that brochure is slightly different, with black hoods and the old style where brake cables come out the top, instead of the internally routed ones on the present bike.

Comment: @ukrutt I suspect it's had new levers - I can't find when concealed routing became common but I think more recently than the rest of the bike was built, and the combination with that stem would seem unlikely

Comment: I personally love the lugless look! [Here's a page about it in an old Peugeot catalogue](https://www.bikeboompeugeot.com/Brochures%20UK/Peugeot%201982%20UK%20Brochure/Peugeot%201982%20UK%20Brochure%20Pg10.jpg).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nice bike!  My hunch is that it's a late 80's bike.  I have a ~1990 Peugeot bike/frame with similar shapes.  You have sliding dropouts, I don't.  What kind of components are on it?

Comment: i dont know honestly.  I dont know much about bikes at all, i just know that Peugeots and Bianchi are excellent bikes.  i picked it up for $20

Comment: Nice!  Could you take a picture of the derailleurs and the brakes?

Comment: please correct if im wrong but Shimano light action

Comment: ok so stupid question, how do i upload another pic in here, i dont see a place

Comment: how do I upload another pic on here, i dont see a way i am able to

Comment: I think you can edit your original post to add another picture.

Comment: I found this resource.  It seems like "Light Action" was introduced in 1986. http://www.disraeligears.co.uk/Site/Shimano_Light_Action_derailleur_L525_SS.html

Comment: added them for you.  thank you very much

Comment: Peugeots of that period were often fitted with Huret or Simplex derailleurs made from plastic parts and rather fragile. So it may have been re-fitted with Shimano parts. Explaining the aero-cables

Answer (score 32):

As noted by @AndrewHenle this appears to be a 1987 or 1988 Peugeot Aubisque; it's a very good match for this (identified as) 1988 catalogue image from [http://www.peugeotshow.com/](http://www.peugeotshow.com/1988fr.html):

[image: 1988 catalogue image of Peugeot Aubisque]

I had previously found a less clear copy of the same catalogue at [www.bikeboompeugeot.com](https://www.bikeboompeugeot.com/Brochures%20France/Peugeot%201987%20France%20Brochure/Peugeot%201987%20France%20Brochure.htm) where it was identified as a 1987 catalogue.  The [1989 catalogue](http://www.peugeotshow.com/1989fr.html) has an Aubisque with a [slightly different paint job](http://www.peugeotshow.com/1989fr/1989fr_13.jpg).

Comment: thats it, you hit the straight on the head on that, it is a Aubisue.  the numbers match 100% PE10D W

Comment: @steverollo Comparing, this is the better answer because it has more details over the accepted answer.

Comment: Out of curiosity - what's the difference between the Saint-Bernard and the Aubisque? The only thing I can see is the paint job and the pedal gear. Is that all?

Comment: @Vilx- Based on a quick translation of the ad copy text, the Aubisque appears to be a lighter weight racing bike, while the Saint-Bernard is presumably more general use?

Comment: One more thing - this got me curious enough to see what history I can dig up on my own old bike. I know that it's a "SANTOSA" brand and it has "18 speed MTB" on it - which is pretty generic, but that's the closest thing to a model that I can find. It's from around 1995. Where can I go look for more leads, if it's at all possible? Quick google search revealed nothing.

Comment: @Vilx- You should ask that as a question; it will get more visibility that way, and you can include pictures.